# How to make Curry and Uncurry dependent types?

Tags: haskell, currying, dependent-type

I was reading a paper by Fridlender and Indrika titled "[Do we need dependent types?](http://www.brics.dk/RS/01/10/BRICS-RS-01-10.pdf)"

In the conclusion, it said that "The same technique can be applied to
other functions like liftM, zip, unzip, curry, uncurry, and taut"

For ZipWith, the authors defined (<<)

```
(<<) :: [a -> b] -> [a] -> [b]
(f:fs) << (a:as) = f a : (fs << as)
_<<_=[]
```

then defined zipWith as

```
(repeat f) << as1 << as2 << .. << asn
```

they then improved it by using a successor function

```
succ :: ([b] -> c) -> [a -> b] -> [a] -> c
succ = \n fs as -> n (fs << as)
```

where the numerals are

```
zero = id
one = succ zero :: [a -> b] -> [a] -> [b]
two = succ one  :: [a -> b -> c] -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
```

and so on ..

finally the dependant type zipWith becomes

```
zipWith :: ([a] -> b) -> a -> b
zipWith n f = n (repeat f)
```

where n is a numeral

But, I am struggling with applying the same technique to curry and uncurry. I can't see how we can manipulate variant size tuples to expand or shrink in size by adding or removing elements respectively. Haskell does not provide such operations. For example, uncurry should have the following type
uncurry :: (a1 -> a2 -> .. -> an -> b) -> (a1,a2,..,an) -> b

How can we have curry and uncurry as dependent types in Haskell?

Comment: Could you please add a brief summary and/or example of the technique you refer to, so that your question becomes self-contained?

Comment: Maybe the authors were thinking of tuples defined recursively (as they are in some languages)? I could see that working out very well.

Comment: thanks @duplode. I included a link to the summary paper and put more information.

Comment: Maybe they mean the same definition of uncurry as was provided [here](https://ro-che.info/articles/2013-01-29-generic-uncurry), so the signature would be `(a1 -> a2 -> ... -> an -> b) -> ((...(a1, a2), ...), an) -> b` instead?